# Hibernating gives me "insufficient resources exist to complete the API"

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate

When I try to hibernate my PC it fails with the following error message if some programs are running, but hibernates perfectly fine otherwise:

> "insufficient resources exist to complete the API".

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Knowledge Base explains that this happens if:

> This problem occurs because the
>   Windows kernel power manager cannot
>   obtain the memory resources that are
>   required to prepare the computer to
>   hibernate.

There is a fix for that, [grab it.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909095)